# Scala Cast Issues : java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing

Tags: scala

I have an Array of Map , that I want to parse and construct a String .
This is how my Map looks :

```
outerArray: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Nothing]] = Array(Map(day -> 2018-08-04, agg_id -> 427912_1_0_1), Map(day -> 2018-09-08, agg_id -> 427912_1_0_2), Map(day -> 2018-10-20, agg_id -> 427912_1_0_3), Map(day -> 2018-10-24, agg_id -> 427912_1_0_4), Map(day -> 2019-09-04, agg_id -> 427912_1_0_5))
```

This my code to form a string for each element in the the outer Array

```
outerArray.foreach(x=>{
     val agg_id_val=x.getOrElse("agg_id","").toString
     val query=x.filterKeys(!_.equals("agg_id"))
               .map{case (key, value) => " " +key + "=" +''' +value +'''+ " "}
               .mkString(" and ")
    println("query"+ query)})
```

I am getting the following error when I run this code . I understand this is due to the value in the inner map , but how do I handle this ?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$
  at $anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:28)
  at $anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:28)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2.foreach(Map.scala:137)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:28)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:26)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
```

I am using scala 2.11.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `Map[String, Any]`, not `Map[String, Nothing]` (of course, a meaningful type would be even better). If you really had a `Map[String, Nothing]` it couldn't contain any values.

Comment: In `Map(day -> 2018-08-04, agg_id -> 427912_1_0_1)`, `2018-08-04` and `427912_1_0_1` are values, so it does have values and can't actually be a `Map[String, Nothing]`. Something is wrong either with the API or with your use of it. As a (temporary) workaround, you could simply cast it: `outerArray.asInstanceOf[Array[Map[String, Any]].foreach...` but it would be better to look at your previous code and figure out where `Nothing` comes from.